# How can I ignore a security scan from alerting in NewRelic?

Tags: newrelic

I am using NewRelic to monitor my cloud env and alert me on high error rate. Twice a day I also run a whitehat security scan on my web site. Of course, the security scan generates errors in my web server, and an alert is triggered in NewRelic.

Is there a way in NewRelic to filter out errors that originate from a specific location, or with a specific header in the incoming request?

I know I can configure my NewRelic agent using a config file and env variable, but I did not find any configuration that might help me here.

Appreciate any leads
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have had success on a team that has implemented an approach which programaticaly notifies New Relic of specific error conditions via the New Relic Agent API so as to exclude them from error reporting.

*Assuming:*

1) You have the ability to instrument your code with the New Relic agent API library (e.g. [.NET agent API](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/net-agent-api)), and

2) You know how to detect when the request originates from White Hat, such as via header or user-agent, then this approach should work for you.

*The Approach:*

For any request flagged as originating from WhiteHat that results in an exception, at the time that the exception is caught, use the New Relic Agent API to [`NoticeError()`](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/net-agent-api/noticeerror-net-agent) and record the error as a special exception type, such as `WhiteHatException`.

For example (.NET syntax):

```
NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.NoticeError(new WhiteHatException());
```

Then filter out `WhiteHatExceptions` from your New Relic error reporting here:

```
Settings -> Application...
Error Collection -> Ignore these Errors:

YourApp.Namespace.WhiteHatException
```

*Note:* You want to do this in some sort of structured fashion, so as to make the error classification and filtering broadly useful and not only for New Relic, if possible.